# Powershell overwriting file contents with match instead of editing single line

Tags: powershell, replace, file-get-contents

I have a text file that contains a string I want to modify.

Example text file contents:

```
abc=1
def=2
ghi=3
```

If I run this code:

```
$file =  "c:\test.txt"
$MinX = 100
$MinY = 100

$a = (Get-Content $file) | %{
    if($_ -match "def=(\d*)"){
        if($Matches[1] -gt $MinX){$_ -replace "$($Matches[1])","$($MinX)" }
    }
}
$a
```

The result is:

`def=100`

If I omit the greater-than check like so:

```
$a = (Get-Content $file) | %{
    if($_ -match "def=(\d*)"){
        $_ -replace "$($Matches[1])","$($MinX)"
    }
}
$a
```

The result is correct:

```
abc=1
def=100
ghi=3
```

I don't understand how a simple integer comparison before doing the replace could screw things up so badly, can anyone advise what I'm missing?

Comment: Both snippets return the same for me, `def=100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator `-gt` will never get you a value of $true because you need to

- cast the $matches[1] **string** value to int first so it compares two integer numbers
- `2` is never greater than `100`.. Change the operator to `-lt` instead.
- Your code outputs only one line, because you forgot to also output unchanged lines that do not match the regex

```
$file = 'c:\test.txt'
$MinX = 100
$MinY = 100

$a = (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^def=(\d+)'){
        if([int]$matches[1] -lt $MinX){ $_ -replace $matches[1],$MinX }
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
}

$a
```

Or use `switch` (is also faster than using Get-Content):

```
$file = 'c:\test.txt'
$MinX = 100
$MinY = 100

$a = switch -Regex -File $file {
    '^def=(\d+)' { 
        if([int]$matches[1] -lt $MinX){ $_ -replace $matches[1],$MinX }
    }
    default { $_ }
}

$a
```

Output:

```
abc=1
def=100
ghi=3
```

Comment: The -gt comparison was succeeding even without forcing to [int], but you were right with needing the 2nd "else $_" to output unchanged lines. I was wrongly expecting them to be included regardless. Especially love the switch idea, this is part of a login script so speed is of the essence. Much appreciated!

Edit: for the curious, changing the file my original way took ~7ms, with Theo's switch it's ~1.4ms

Answer (score 0):

That's because the expression `($Matches[1] -gt $MinX)` is a string comparison. In Powershell, the left-hand side of a comparison dictates the comparison type and since that is of type `[string]`, Powershell has to cast/convert the right-hand side of the expression to `[string]` also. You expression, therefore, is evaluated as `([string]$Matches[1] -gt [string]$MinX)`.